# I want to display specific images under different categories of projects. Instead, my app is showing all images under each category

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Here is my App.js has code for all the categories including the Home.js that has links to the categories

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Header from './components/layouts/Header'
import Footer from './components/layouts/Footer'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Ceiling from './components/Ceiling'
import Floor from './components/Floor'
import Walls from './components/Walls'
import ProjectDetails from './components/project/ProjectDetails'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <div className="container "> 

          <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>

          <Route path="/ceiling" component={Ceiling} exact/>

          <Route path="/floor" component={Floor} exact/>

          <Route path="/walls" component={Walls} exact/>

          <Route path="/project/:id" component={ProjectDetails} exact/>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}



export default App;
```

Here is the Home page with code that links to the categories

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'
//import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import MetaData from './layouts/MetaData'


const Home = () => {




  return (

   <Fragment>
    <MetaData title={'See my projects'}/>
    <h6 className='top-tag font-size-16 font-rale text-dark sticky2 bg-light py-3'>See my <strong>projects</strong> below...</h6>
    <div className='page-container'>
    
      <div className="page-list text-center">
        <Link to={`./Ceiling`}><img src="./images/moodceiling.jpg" className="thumbnail image-resize2"/></Link>
        <div className="flex-div">
          <div className="page-info">
            <Link to={`./Ceiling`} className="text-dark font-rubik font-size-16">Ceiling design&nbsp;(8)</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="page-list text-center">
        <Link to={`./Walls`}><img src="./images/walls.jpg" className="thumbnail image-resize2"/></Link>
        <div className="flex-div">
          <div className="page-info">
            <Link to={`./Walls`} className="text-dark font-rubik font-size-16">Wall finishes&nbsp;(25)</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="page-list text-center">
        <Link to={`./Floor`}><img src="./images/epoxxy.jpeg" className="thumbnail image-resize2"/></Link>
        <div className="flex-div">
          <div className="page-info">
            <Link to={`./Floor`} className="text-dark font-rubik font-size-16">Floor finishes&nbsp;(73)</Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
   </Fragment>

  )
}

export default Home
```

My Ceiling.js page returns all projects from all categories on screen. I want it to render images of projects under ceiling category only. same to walls and floors

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Pagination from "react-js-pagination";

import MetaData from "./layouts/MetaData";
import Project from "./project/Project";
import Loader from "./layouts/Loader";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useAlert } from "react-alert";
import { getProjects } from "../actions/projectActions";


const Ceiling = ({ match }) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);


  const alert = useAlert();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { loading, projects, error, projectsCount, resPerPage } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.projects
  );

  const keyword = match.params.keyword;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      return alert.error(error);
    }
    dispatch(getProjects( currentPage));
  }, [dispatch, alert, error, currentPage]);

  function setCurrentPageNo(pageNumber) {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <MetaData title={"Ceilings"} />
          <div className="sticky2 bg-light">
            <h6 className="top-tag font-size-16 font-rale text-dark ">
              See the projects on <strong>Ceilings</strong> below...
            </h6>

          </div>

          <div className="page-container ">
            {projects &&
              projects.map((project) => (
                <Project key={project._id} project={project} />
              ))}
          </div>
          {resPerPage <= projectsCount && (
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
              <Pagination
                activePage={currentPage}
                itemsCountPerPage={resPerPage}
                totalItemsCount={projectsCount}
                onChange={setCurrentPageNo}
                nextPageText={"Next"}
                prevPageText={"Prev"}
                firstPageText={"First"}
                lastPageText={"Last"}
                itemClass="page-item"
                linkClass="page-link"
              />
            </div>
          )}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Ceiling;
```

similarly my Walls.js page does the same, renders images of all projects on the frontend.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination'

import MetaData from "./layouts/MetaData";
import Project from "./project/Project";
import Loader from "./layouts/Loader";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert'
import { getProjects } from "../actions/projectActions";

const Walls = ({ match }) => {

  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)

  const alert = useAlert();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const { loading, projects, error, projectsCount, resPerPage  } = useSelector(state => state.projects)

    const keyword = match.params.keyword

    useEffect(() => {

      if(error) {

        return alert.error(error)
      }
      dispatch(getProjects(keyword, currentPage));
  
    }, [dispatch, alert, error, keyword, currentPage]);

    function setCurrentPageNo(pageNumber) {
      setCurrentPage(pageNumber)
    }


  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? <Loader/> : (
        <Fragment>
               <MetaData title={"Walls"} />
      <div className="sticky2 bg-light">
        <h6 className="top-tag font-size-16 font-rale text-dark ">
           See projects on <strong>Wall Finishes</strong> below...
        </h6>

      </div>

      <div className="page-container ">

        {projects && projects.map(project => (

          <Project key={project._id} project={project}/>

        ))}

      </div>

      {resPerPage <= projectsCount && (
              <div className="d-flex justify-content-center mt-5">
              <Pagination
                          activePage={currentPage}
                          itemsCountPerPage={resPerPage}
                          totalItemsCount={projectsCount}
                          onChange={setCurrentPageNo}
                          nextPageText ={'Next'}
                          prevPageText ={'Prev'}
                          firstPageText ={'First'}
                          lastPageText ={'Last'}
                          itemClass='page-item'
                          linkClass="page-link"
              />
            </div>
      )}


        </Fragment>
      )}
 
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default Walls
```

For convenience below is my model for projects

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')



const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter project name'],
        trim: true,
        maxLength: [200, 'image name cannot exceed 200 characters']
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter project description'],
    },
    images: [
        {
            public_id: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            url: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },
        }
    ],
 
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select category for this project'],
        enum: {
            values: [
                'Floor finishes',
                'Ceiling design', 
                'Wall finishes',
            ],
            message: 'Please select correct category for project'
        }
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

For the backend, this is my API that fetches projects from database

```
// Get all projects => /api/v1/projects?keyword=curtain
exports.getProjects = catchAsyncErrors ( async (req, res, next) => {

    

    const resPerPage = 12;
    const projectsCount = await Project.countDocuments();

    const apiFeatures = new APIFeatures(Project.find(), req.query)
        .search()
        .filter()
        .pagination(resPerPage)

    const projects = await apiFeatures.query;


        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            projectsCount,
            resPerPage,
            projects
        })


})
```